# Postgres source SQL for existing table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I need to extract the source SQL for an existing table in postgres. Is it is possible?

Example: If I  have a customertable, created in pgadmin, with 2 columns: id (integer), name (text). Is there way I can extract/get the CREATE function for this existing table, so I get a SQL with “CREATE TABLE customer ...” without having to write the whole SQL of the table in hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- pgadmin (III,4):

right click on table name -> Scripts-> CREATE sript

- psql:

  ```
  pg_dump -s -t table_name
  ```